# Kotlin RecyclerView: listener not working

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

new to Kotlin.I have a recyclerview working good, except the setOnClicklistener. Click on the row are not detected.

OnClick is not called.

```
class RecyclerAdapter (private var listener: OnItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var title = arrayOf ("Calibration", "Unit in ft", "Voice system", "Vario sound", "Pull warning", "ADD warning", "Alt. warning" )
    private var images = intArrayOf(R.drawable.altitud24, R.drawable.straighten24, R.drawable.volume24, R.drawable.volume24,R.drawable.report24,R.drawable.report24,R.drawable.report24)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textview.text = title[position]
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return title.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        val itemImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageRecycler)
        val textview: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRecycler)

        init{
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            println("bouton pushed ------------ $position ***************************")
            val position:Int = absoluteAdapterPosition
            listener.OnItemClick(position)
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun OnItemClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized that connecting the listener to the textview is working, but cannot understand why it does not work with itemView????

Comment: i had test your case it work just fine.

Comment: but for single action i don't think it best practice with Kotlin by using interface. I gonna drop the Kotlin way for that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
 init{
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
            }
    
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                println("bouton pushed ------------ $position ***************************")
                val position:Int = absoluteAdapterPosition
                listener.OnItemClick(position)
            }
```

with this and check if it works for you.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener { view ->
                    val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
                    println("bouton pushed ------------ $position ***************************")
                    listener.OnItemClick(position)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a onClickListener in "onBindViewHolder". For your code, you can put it to your "onBindViewHolder";

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    println("bouton pushed ------------ $position ***************************")
    listener.OnItemClick(position)
}
```

Position will be already available in onBindViewHolder. So you dont need to define another position.

Answer (score 0):

in your inner class replace :

```
        init{
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
```

by :

```
        init{
        itemView.setOnClickListener(adapterPosition)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion by block as Kotlin style

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private var listener: (Int) -> Unit) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>()
```

In your **onBindViewHolder**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
      listener(position)
}
```

You are now free with interface , shorter and cleaner code!